# Firefox checkbox:checked background

Tags: css, firefox, checkbox

I am customizing checkbox and I have a problem with the background. In Chrome everything is ok but in Firefox there is no background. There is CSS code with background. Please can you tell me what is wrong?

```
.box-filter input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
background: #000000;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can set the background colour of a checkbox in any browser. The following test shows me a normal checkbox in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/9evGF/

Comment: Same with Firefox.  Can you include a screen shot of what you see in Chrome?

Comment: Please see this question for answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible in most major browsers, which is why a lot of sites implement their own versions of checkboxes using an image for consistent experience.  As for Firefox specifically, there is a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183247) for it (since [CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background-color) does stipulate that background-color applies to all elements), but it has been resolved as "Won't Fix".

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do custom checkboxes is with an `<a>` tag. Then you can style them in all kinds of ways, and have an `<input type="hidden" value="0">` accompany each one to store it's value. Then you can access its value in a form submission. jQuery takes care of the actual functionality.

HTML:

```
<a class="pseudo-checkbox" data-role="checkbox" data-checked="0"></a>
<input type="hidden" name="terms" value="0">
```

The CSS below demonstrates using `:before` pseudo element to style the box, slightly smaller than the `<a>` element itself so that the checkmark can overlap the box. An icon-font is used to add a checkmark which will look great on any screen.

```
a.pseudo-checkbox {
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:24px;
    height:24px;
    position:relative;
}
a.pseudo-checkbox:before {
    content:"";
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    left:0;
    bottom:2px;
    display:block;
    border:1px #868686 solid;
    background-color:white;
}
a.pseudo-checkbox:active:before {
    background-color:gray;
}
a.pseudo-checkbox i.icon-checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
    color:#028208;
    float:none;
    margin:0;
    font-size:18px;
    top:0;
    left:2px;
}
```

HTML:

JS (jQuery):

```
$('a[data-role=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
    var checked = $(this).attr('data-checked');
    var self = $(this);
    if (checked == 0) {
        self.html('<i class="icon-checkmark"></i>');
        self.attr('data-checked', 1);
        self.siblings('input').val(1);
    } else {
        self.html('');
        self.attr('data-checked', 0);
        self.siblings('input').val(0);
    }
});
```